# Issues with looping a program to set format to general for the cells in selection

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set the format of all the cells in multiple worksheets in a workbook to general format so that my charts will update with the proper data displayed. This works well on a single active page but i cannot get it to loop properly as it is also very slow.

```
Sub SettingFormatToGeneral()
 Dim works As Worksheet
  For Each works In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Range("A:Q").Select 'specify the range which suits your purpose
    With Selection
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
    End With
  Next works
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UsedRange` to limit your data set.

```
 Sub SettingFormatToGeneral()
     Dim works As Worksheet
      For Each works In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'specify the range which suits your purpose
        With works.UsedRange.Resize(, 17) '/ Only refer the used range and columns A:Q.
            .NumberFormat = "General"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
      Next works
    End Sub
```